# How to color the last word added in text with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function that returns a string every time I'm clicking a button.
Every time the button is clicked I want the string to be added to my widget text. But I want the last string added to be in red (and the text added before in black).

I didn't find an easy way to make it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look through the **Tags** section here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

You can set this up pretty easily by making a couple of tags (using the `tag_config()` method on a `Text` widget), let's call them `highlight` and `unhighlight`:

```
text.tag_config('highlight', foreground='red')
text.tag_config('unhighlight', foreground='black')
```

Then, in your `Button` callback, attach these tags to the text:

```
def callback():
    # unhighlight everything from the beginning to the end
    text.tag_add('unhighlight', 1.0, END)

    # insert new text and apply the highlight tag to it
    text.insert(END, 'hello world ', 'highlight')
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfectly what I wanted to.

Comment: Instead of an "unhighlight" tag, you can simply remove the "highlight" tag for all of the text before adding the new word.